# constexpr: gcc is trying harder to eval constexpr than clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17, constexpr

I'm using godbolt to see generated code with gcc and clang.

I tried to implement to [djb2 hash](https://godbolt.org/z/onKnRZ).

gcc always trying is best to eval constexpr function.

clang is evaluating constexpr only if the variable is constexpr.

Let's see the example:

```
constexpr int djb2(char const *str)
{
    int hash = 5381;
    int c = 0;

    while ((c = *str++))
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
        return hash;
}

int main()
{
    int i = djb2("hello you :)");
}
```

With this example, gcc is evaluating a compile time i. But clang at run time.

If I add constexpr to `i`, clang is evaluating also at compile time.

Do you know if the standard is saying something about that ?

EDIT: thanks to all. So, as I understand, without constexpr the compiler is doing what is want. With constexpr, the compiler is forced to evaluating the constant.

Comment: Both compilers are correct: the function is `constexpr` and the argument is a literal, so the compiler can exec it compile time; the variable, `i`, isn't `constexpr`, so the compiler isn't obliged to exec the function compile time. In this case, a compiler is free to exec compile or let the execution go run-time.

Comment: @max66 Prior to C++20 and `consteval`, you cannot get a guarantee for compile time execution of your code. Even if `i` was constexpr, the compiler does not have to calculate its value during compile time unless it is used in a compile time context (for example as template argument). So yeah, both compilers are right, and it would be right according to the standard to do even less at compile time than clang.

Comment: This is intentional. It is to facilitate debugging. When a function is ran at runtime, you can debug it. Try compiling your code on release and it will be constant evaluated.

Comment: @eike: `constexpr int i = djb2("hello you :)");` **is** a compile time context.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, that wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior.

The shift `hash << 5` will overflow which has undefined behavior for signed integer types before C++20.

In particular that means that calling your function can never yield a constant expression, which you can verify by adding `constexpr` to your declaration of `i`. Both compilers will then have to diagnose the undefined behavior and will tell you about it.

Give `hash` an unsigned type and your code will actually have well-defined behavior and the expression `djb2("hello you :)"` will actually be a constant expression that *can be* evaluated at compile-time, assuming you are using C++14 or later (The loop was not allowed in a `constexpr` function in C++11.).

This still doesn't require the compiler to actually do the evaluation at compile-time, but then you can force it by adding `constexpr` to the declaration of `i`.

"*Force*" here is relative. Because of the *as-if rule* and because there is no *observable* difference between evaluation at compile-time and runtime, the compiler is still not technically required to really do the computation only at compile-time, but it requires the compiler to check the whole calculation for validity, which is basically the same as evaluating it, so it would be unreasonable for the compiler to repeat the evaluation at runtime.

Similarly "*can be evaluated at compile-time*" is relative as well. Again for the same reasons as above, a compiler can still choose to do the calculations at compile-time even if it is not a constant expression as long as there wouldn't be any observable difference in behavior. This is purely a matter of optimizer quality. In your specific case the program has undefined behavior, so the compilers can choose to do what they want anyway.

Comment: Does making `i` `constexpr` actually **force** compile time evaluation of `djb2`? I thought that was only possible with C++20's `consteval`

Comment: Singed integer underflow/overflow is still UB in C++20

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Not according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). I will check the draft later.

Comment: «Your program has undefined behavior»
Oh my… you are right. But I have the same result with unsigned int.

Comment: @eike Yes `constexpr` on a variable (but not on a function) forces compile-time evaluation of the initializer expression. (*As-if* rule non-withstanding.)

Comment: @walnut Thank you, I missed this part of the constexpr specification.

Comment: Strictly speaking, whether or not the compiler evaluates some constant expression at compile time is not observable behaviour, so the standard cannot guarantee it. That being said, if you do initialize a `constexpr` variable with the result, the compiler is forced to determine whether the expression is actually a constant expression, which means it might as well evaluate it. Similarly if you use the value in a template argument then the compiler must diagnose any consequences of instantiating the template with that value.

Comment: @walnut it seem you're right for the shift operator. But it still say that signed integer arithmeric overflow is undefined behaviour. I'm confused there.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Yes, I think that is intended. Shift overflow is well-defined, but additive overflow is not.

Comment: And double thanks, I didn't know that signed shifting was allowed in c++20.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot The current draft [mentions](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift) undefined behavior for the shift operators only in the case where the right-hand side is negative or too large. So I think cppreference.com is correct in that signed shift overflow will have well-defined behavior (discarding the bits shifted outside the range). I think this is a consequence of the integer types representation being required to be two's complement in C++20.

Comment: @VincentLEGARREC Sorry, I overlooked your first comment. Do you still get runtime evaluation with `constexpr int i =`?

Comment: No, compilers are doing what I was expected. I was just wondering why clang and gcc was having different behaviors without ``constexpr``

Comment: @VincentLEGARREC If you fix the undefined behavior, both Clang and GCC optimize away everything if optimizations are enabled, even without `constexpr` on the variable, see https://godbolt.org/z/_7fA_g.

Comment: Wait, can someone explain to me why `5381 << 5` will overflow? Is that not still well within `int` range?

Comment: @JohnIlacqua It is within the range on the first iteration of the loop. But OP repeats the statement twelve times. This gives an effective shift of about 60 bits. Together with the already 12 or so in 5381 that gives more than 64 which is sure to overflow for any typical standard integer type.

Comment: Oh right, the loop. The strange indentation threw me off.